# Заметил странного пользователя

Tags: обсуждение

Есть пользователь [turik97](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218290/turik97). Последний вопрос/ответ от 4 июня сего года, но комментарии пишет активно ...

К вопросам (и ответам на них) заданным **незарегистрированными** пользователями, как будто это его вопросы.

Что думаете по этому поводу? :)

P.S. Эти вопросы не имеют принятых ответов.

**UPD** Еще один странный пользователь - [Дмитрий Гончаров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/222613/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2). Дает ответы и делает их общими.

Comment: Вот вам и [ответ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yhbZ.png)

Comment: @Nikita, спасибо за подтверждение моей паранойи :)

Comment: Кстати, интересно какова политика администрации по отношению к виртуалам, если те не используются для накрутки голосов?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, думаю, ваш комментарий стоит оформить отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev насколько я знаю, виртуалы ликвидируются только когда они используются для нарушения правил (кроме накрутки это может быть грубость/оскорбления во время бана основного аккаунта, или обход блокировки на вопросы или ответы). Непосредственно на виртуалов запретов я не припоминаю.